# not able to retrieve data from sharedPrference in intra fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-sharedpreferences

Sending data of sharedpreference
This is interface for communication

```
@Override
public void saveBMI(String d, String r, String f_r) {
    sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("userBMI",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("CheckDate",d);
    editor.putString("BmiResult",r);
    editor.putString("BmiWeight",f_r);
    editor.commit();
}
```

**This method I use for sending data from shared preference to another fragment**

```
@Override
public void showBMI() {
    if(sharedPreferences.contains("CheckDate"))
    {
        c_d=sharedPreferences.getString("CheckDate","");
    }
    if(sharedPreferences.contains("BmiResult"))
    {
        bmi_res=sharedPreferences.getString("BmiResult","");
    }
    if(sharedPreferences.contains("BmiWeight"))
    {
        bmi_w=sharedPreferences.getString("BmiWeight","");
    }

 //here i want to send the data to another fragment ...???



}
```

Comment: Call code in onResume() method...

Comment: which code @Exception Lover

Comment: Shared Preferences should be accessed via singleton object. If you create new object everytime then you will not get data from shared preferences.

Comment: this code if(sharedPreferences.contains("CheckDate"))
    {
        c_d=sharedPreferences.getString("CheckDate","");
    }
    if(sharedPreferences.contains("BmiResult"))
    {
        bmi_res=sharedPreferences.getString("BmiResult","");
    }
    if(sharedPreferences.contains("BmiWeight"))
    {
        bmi_w=sharedPreferences.getString("BmiWeight","");
    }

Answer (score 0):

The point of shared preferences is that you can access it from everywhere, so in the other fragment just get the data you want.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
prefs.getString("CheckDate","");
```

If your question is about how to send data from a fragment to another I recommend using the newInstance method when creating a fragment and passing the arguments there.

```
public static GenericAreaFragment newInstance(String color, String title, String areaId, boolean isArea) {
    GenericAreaFragment frag = new GenericAreaFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(COLOR, color);
    args.putString(TITLE, title);
    args.putString(AREA_ID, areaId);
    args.putBoolean(ISAREA, isArea);
    frag.setArguments(args);
    return frag;
}
```

Then you can get the arguments with:

```
getArguments().getBoolean(ISAREA); // or getString, etc
```

Many explanations are in the android documentation along with how to communicate through activities and fragments.

http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/Fragment.html